# Encryption and decryption purely

Tags: encryption

I have a string of length 64 characters, I have to convert that into string of length 16 characters. Can you please guide me through the encryption method which encrypts the string of  64 characters into string of 16 characters and also when I decrypt the 16 characters string, I need to get the 64 characters string back.

Comment: Show us some inputs and the desired outputs.

Comment: If the 64-character string is in hexidecimal this might be possible. (As each character in hexidecimal can be represented by four 0-9A-F letters)

Comment: Also adding !!! doesn't add any clarity. ;)

Comment: I'm interested in a solution for this too. I have this `movie.avi` containing about 6 billion characters and I'd really like to get it down to about one hundred characters...

Comment: Sounds like fun.  Did you have a question, or were you just sharing that with us?  BTW - those words are spelled 'you/please', not 'u/pls'.

Comment: @aix-String= 76702C92F77D4CE827ED8DA71C4AECE63AF1539B0430820F994FA8D7B5916F91,,i need this string of length 64 char to be converted into string of length 16 char say "u90ttyyyuuuiii22".If i decrypt u90ttyyyuuuiii22 i need to get string of length 64 char back.

Comment: Looks like some 256-bit hash in hex form. Are you trying to find a preimage of an arbitrary SHA256 hash? If you succeed, you will be recognized as the most notable cryptographer of the decade!

Answer (score 7):

You can't.

Generally, you can't put 64 bytes (or characters) of information into 16 bytes (or characters) without losing some data.

You can try to compress it and if you're lucky the data compresses to 16 bytes or less, but that depends on the input and will definitely not work on all input.

Comment: In other words - the problem description is probably not correct.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I believe we don't see a problem description at all. We see a question about the implementation of a proposed solution. And that solution is impossible to implement.

Comment: @Joachim, "... I have to...", hence my conclusion.

Comment: Note that there is a simple mathematical proof what the OP is trying to do is impossible.

Comment: @Adam - you are correct.  `1 !=2`.  However, I fail to see that this is relevant.  FWIW - the proof involves counting states.  (And yes, this is an "obvious" result to you and me.  But there are millions of people out there who imagine ... for example ... that compressing a compressed file will make it even smaller.  And supposedly smart business folks who have been conned into investing in hyper-compression snake oil schemes.)

Comment: @Adam - and apparently, the OP is one such person who thinks it ought to be possible ...

Comment: @Stephen C: Well, the OP does say that they only have *one* 64 character string.  That being the case, it can be compressed down to nothing at all ;)